# PHP cURL not rendering requested webpage

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to figure out if my server can make outbound https request(more specifically port 443) by using cURL, but the code is neither loading any page content nor giving any error.

```
<?php
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo $response;

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

I am new to the use of cURL, but shouldnt it load the content of google's home page?

Answer (score 1):

to actually get the response you must add:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

don't scrape google, even to test, they actively detect and stop this

Comment: Is there any url that i can use in this purpose to figure out if outward https requests are working or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send request to https server,sometimes you also need these two options:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);`